# How to handle empty/incomplete subsets with data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I have a panel of data with year, country, and firm identifiers. I would like to fit logit models to each year-country subset using `data.table`. I don't have a problem if I have enough entries in each year-country subset to fit a model, but if there are not enough data in a year-country subset, then `glm` throws an error and I can't fit all the models. (I get essentially the same error with `lm`.)

Is there a solution within `data.table`? Or should I groom my data upstream to make sure there are no year-country subsets without insufficient data?

Thanks!

```
library(data.table)

# similar data
DT <- data.table(year=rep(2001:2010, each=100),
                 country=rep(rep(1:10, each=10), 10), 
                 firm=rep(1:100, 10), 
                 y=round(runif(100)), 
                 x=runif(100)
                 )
setkey(DT, year, country)

# no problems if there are enough data per year-country subset
DT2 <- DT[, as.list(coef(glm(y ~ x), family="binomial")), by="year,country"]

# but `lm` throws and error if there are missing data
DT[(DT$year == 2001) & (DT$country == 1), "y"] <- NA
DT3 <- DT[, as.list(coef(glm(y ~ x, family="binomial"))), by="year,country"]
```

yields

```
> DT3 <- DT[, as.list(coef(glm(y ~ x, family="binomial"))), by="year,country"]
Error in family$linkfun(mustart) : 
  Argument mu must be a nonempty numeric vector
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about this?

```
fn <- function(x, y) {
  if (length(na.omit(y)) == 0)
    NULL
  else
    as.list(coef(glm(y ~ x, family="binomial")))
}

DT3 <- DT[, fn(x, y), by="year,country"]
```

You can obviously tailor error-checking in `fn` for your specific purposes.

**Update**. Here is a solution if you want `fn` to potentially process several columns in your data table:

```
fn <- function(df) {
  if (length(na.omit(df$y)) == 0)
    NULL
  else
    as.list(coef(glm(df$y ~ df$x, family="binomial")))
}

DT3 <- DT[, fn(.SD), by="year,country"]
```

---

**Edit from Matthew**

That isn't quite how you're supposed to use `data.table`. No need to define a function. Just use the variables directly like this:

```
DT3 <- DT[, 
  if (length(na.omit(y)) == 0)
    NULL
  else
    as.list(coef(glm(y ~ x, family="binomial")))
, by="year,country"]
```

The repetition of `df$` inside `fn()` and calling `fn(.SD)` isn't recommended in `data.table` unless you really are using all the columns of `.SD` e.g. by using `.SDcols`.  It is common to have quite a large multi-line `{ ... }` as `j`.

Comment: Good point! Thanks (I've been using too much Stata, where wrappers are a hassle)! Is there a way to more easily pass 5+ arguments to `fn` with `data.table`? It seems that I have to pass them vector-by-vector as you've done/

Comment: Sure. You can make ``fn`` take a data frame (or data table) as a parameter and call it like this: ``fn(.SD)`` in your data.table call. See ``?data.table`` for help on ``.SD``, ``.N`` and other useful arguments.

Comment: Thanks for the lesson, Victor!

Comment: +1 @RichardHerron Agreed wrappers are a hassle. Have added edit showing the idiomatic data.table usage which doesn't need a wrapper (should also be faster).